# Complete dataset of NYC building units

Tags: data-request, buildings

I am looking for a dataset that shows the number of units in each NYC building. The most complete dataset on NYC buildings that I've come across so far is the [PLUTO](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-pluto-mappluto.page) dataset, which is referenced by [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-buildings) as being:

> a master record of the locations and characteristics of buildings in New York City.

However, the latest version of this dataset has 858k rows and according to [other sources](https://ny.curbed.com/2018/4/23/17271092/manhattan-buildings-data-visualization-taylor-baldwin), there are > 1 million buildings in NYC.

Does anyone know why some buildings are excluded and if there is a more complete dataset to analyze the number of units in buildings?